# How can I transform a list (horizontal) in a dataframe on Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Consider the following list on Python:

```
B = ['          JOBID     USER      ACCOUNT           NAME  ST  TIME_LEFT NODES CPUS TRES_PER_N MIN_MEM NODELIST (REASON) ',

 '       48752673    emdim def-danilobz            Sex  PD    1:15:00     1   10        N/A   3000M  (Priority) ',

 '       48752675    emdim def-danilobz            Age  PD    1:15:00     1   10        N/A   3000M  (Priority) ',

 '       48752676    emdim def-danilobz Age_completed_  PD    1:15:00     1   10        N/A   3000M  (Priority) ',

 '       48752678    emdim def-danilobz  Year_of_birth  PD    1:15:00     1   10        N/A   3000M  (Priority) ',

 '']
```

Is there a way to transform it into a pandas dataframe, such as the first item of the list is the first row of the dataframe, etc?
I thought about using loop, but I feel there is a more efficient method?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you want to transpose the dataframe:

```
df.transpose()
```

Comment: no, I have a list and I want to transform it into a dataframe.